# Dealing with international agency client that's not paying

Tags: client-relations

So I'm having trouble getting an international agency to send me my money. They had dragged out the project that was supposed to last a week into 2+ months. About two months ago I asked for payment and they said ok. I sent the invoice and a month later, nothing. Emailed them and they said I need an accounting code that they were supposed to give me but didn't. That took a couple of weeks to get, and now I'm back waiting for them to send the money.

I've been told that I can invoice them for the majority of the payment now, and the rest they still have to get clearance on. However, they want to do this via wire transfer for which I will incur a fee for each transfer.

I'm not sure how to proceed at this time - should I try reaching their head accountant? It's been hard to reach anyone by phone and I get a generic VM for their stateside office. Sounds shady, but the company appears to be legit from their website and other online findings. It seems like there's a lot of red tape going on, but that's no excuse for this delay. Should these guys pay the wire fees? I feel like they should, but that might mean waiting a year for them to get that cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Hassle them - and do so by email if you can so that you retain a chain of your, and their, responses.

Definitely do try to get hold of someone in accounts, but keep each and every one of your contacts in the loop - ccd in on each email - so that they can't forget you.

Suggest breaking up your fee into chunks. It might even be worth using the phrase "I can do this if you are having a problem finding the funds" - it's amazing how that shames some businesses into action.

With the wire fee add on a handling cost to each invoice. If they question it it's a bargaining chip for you. (It's better to be paid something than nothing though.) If you do split your invoice into 'easy monthly payments' for them, then you definitely add back the wire fee on to each one - you are doing them a favour, so shouldn't be charged for it.

Comment: I got on the phone in the middle of the night to hassle their HQ. Seems like they're a total wreck in the accounting dept. If the delay keeps going, I'll try your shaming technique. Others on the internets have mentioned social media shaming to encourage payment.

Answer (score 0):

My advise, move on. Its gone.

Take this as a rule forever going forward, even for friends and family. If you're running a business: **take payment up front! NO EXCEPTIONS!**

If that doesn't fly - take a deposit - but don't release any artwork till you have recieved the balance. Send them password protected files etc.

I can't stress this enough. If I could put it on a bill board and fly it to your house, I would.

When you take payment upfront you will be in control. Not them. If they haven't paid, they will do everything not to pay or to delay payment.

I learned this the hard way and it seems you have too.

Comment: While your advice to get payment upfront is good, I don't agree with just giving up. That seems like a self-defeating attitude to have and it would be quitting prematurely.